# How do received variable from slot method with using PYQT5 python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

The following is my code and sample GUI. I'm doing a data extractor application using PYQT5 (Python). However, I have a problem with how to pass the variable from  QlineEdit to the init method after the browse button has clicked. The program flow is when I click the browse button, it will open file explorer let me choose either one folder. Second, the folder path have set in QlineEdit. However, I can't get the folder path variable.

[image]

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

        self.dis_folder = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dis_folder.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 311, 31))
        self.dis_folder.setObjectName("dis_folder")

        self.btn_browse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_browse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 60, 91, 31))
        self.btn_browse.setObjectName("btn_browse")

        self.dis_log = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.dis_log.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 311, 341))
        self.dis_log.setObjectName("dis_log")

        self.lbl_Folder = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_Folder.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 71, 31))
        self.lbl_Folder.setObjectName("lbl_Folder")

        self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 150, 91, 31))
        self.btn_start.setObjectName("btn_start")

        self.btn_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_stop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 210, 91, 31))
        self.btn_stop.setObjectName("btn_stop")

class MyMainForm(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):




  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.folderPath = ""
    super(MyMainForm, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.btn_browse.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

    print(self.folderPath)

    # self.dis_log.setText(self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.readXML(folderPath)))

def openFile(self):
    get_directory_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                "select XML folder.",
                                "C:/")

    self.dis_folder.setText(str(get_directory_path))
    if  self.folderPath=="":
        self.folderPath=get_directory_path
    def readXML(self,dir):

        main.runReadXML("r\'"+str(dir)+"\'")
        # print("r\'"+str(get_directory_path)+"\'")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWin = MyMainForm()
    myWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: By the time the button is pressed `MyMainForm.__init__` has long finished executing. You could store the path in an instance variable from within `openFile`, e.g. `self.folderPath = get_directory_path`

Comment: Thanks, but how do i call the folderPath variable without openFile method or pass the variable into readXML method?

Comment: Via `self.folderPath` like any other instance variable.

Comment: Sorry, I new for PYQT5. It has error  " print(self.folderPath)
AttributeError: 'MyMainForm' object has no attribute 'folderPath'"

Comment: `self.folderPath` won't be set until the user presses the button. You could initialize it in `MainMainWindow.__init__` and give it a default value (e.g. empty string, or None). To use it in other functions you would need to check if it has a sensible value before using it (e.g. `if self.folderPath: do_something_with_path`)

Comment: I have added self.folderPath = "" in MainWindow.__int__, but the self.folderPath is null, it didnt has received value from openFile method

Comment: Like I said, it won't be set to a sensible value until the user presses the `Browse` button, i.e. after the GUI has been set up and is showing on the screen. Until then it will have a default value.

Comment: Yup, I have clicked the browse button, but it didnt show up anything